# TryStrToDateTime ignores trailing characters in string ("false positive")

Tags: string, validation, datetime, delphi

I am writing a data import utility to import data into a database application. The data can be retrieved from the clipboard (e.g. from Excel) or a file and is initially stored in a TStringlist.  In the next step the user can select the appropriate column separator (tab, comma, etc.).  After splitting the data into columns (using the selected separator), each string value (let's call it a cell value) is checked for validity against the applicable database field type.

The issue I'm having is with datetime values (and possibly date and/or time value, but I haven't checked that yet).  If the user selects the "wrong" separator, the data is not split and each line contains a single column (which is correct, of course).  In such a case, the cell value may contain a string like the one below (I am showing the debug value to show the correct separator, tab in this case):

'04/01/10 00:00'#9'2.50'#9'100'#9'Text value'

When using TryStrToDateTime or StrToDatetime, this string value "passes" because the string is "clipped" (i.e. ignoring the trailing text and returning the correct datetime value of 04/01/10).  If I then, at a later stage, pass the cell value (the original string) as a variant to a range comparison function, it obviously fails with an EVariantTypeCastError.

Is there a method (or existing Delphi RTL function) to check for the string value to contain a valid date(time) only (i.e. no trailing text)? Unable to find a function (or function parameter) taking this into account, I have also been thinking about checking string length but my software is used internationally and the datetime format will therefore be varying and may thus have different lengths.

PS: I have added below sample code here as I couldn't add it to my comments.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  lStrVal: string;
  lIsDateTime: boolean;
  lDateTimeVal: TDateTime;
begin

  lStrVal := '01/01/2019 10:00' + chr(9) + '120.00' + chr(9) + 'Some text';

  lIsDateTime := TryStrToDateTime(lStrVal, lDateTimeVal);

  if lIsDateTime then
    messageDlg('String value is a date/time! ' + #13#10 + 'String: ' + lStrVal + #13#10 + 'Date/time is: ' + DateTimeToStr(lDateTimeVal), mtInformation, [mbOK], 0)
  else
    messageDlg('String value cannot be converted to a date/time!', mtWarning, [mbOK], 0);
end;
```

Comment: It seems you are neglecting the return value (boolean) of `TryStrToDateTime()` as it returns `False` with your test string, although the `TDateTime` value might be correct. Thus you will also not detect a real date time error. But if you are happy with that, you also have the function you are asking for. Just convert back to string the date time you have got, in order to strip off any rubbish after the date time in the original string?

Comment: @TomBrunberg; Actually I am not neglecting the return value.  Please consider the code I have added to my question.  You'll have to take my word for the return value being 'true'.

Comment: Then, perhaps there is a difference in Delphi versions. I'm using XE7, what are you using?

Comment: Delphi 10.3 Rio. Are you saying the function works correctly (i.e. returns false) with XE7?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, trailing characters are ignored for some reasons. What you see is that the date time format does not fit your locale settings. Just enter a valid date time string followed by som extra irrellevant characters, and the function will return true.

Comment: @LU RD; That's exactly what I am trying to demonstrate with my sample code (added to question).

Comment: Yes Mark and @LURD, you are right! In my test yesterday I used `TryStrToDate()` (which returns false in said case) despite what I wrote in my first comment. So Mark, there you have your function you asked for. Maybe you also can simplify your range comparison using `TDateTime` values instead of `string` values.

Comment: I wonder if this is a bug introduced in a specific Delphi version (changes in function) or "as designed". In the latter case it is strange that TryStrToDate seems to work as expected (as suggested by Tom). Will do some further experimenting as the change to using TDateTime values for range comparison has quite some implications in my code.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the solution (at least for my application) is to **combine** TryStrToDateTime and TryStrToDate.  To demonstrate, start a new VCL application and drop a ListBox and TButton on the form (leave standard names).  Paste the following code in the TButton OnClick handler:

```
var
  lDateVal, lDateTimeVal: TDateTime;
  lStrVal: string;
  lResult: boolean;
begin
  ListBox1.Items.Clear;

  lStrVal := '01/01/2019 10:00' + '-120.00' + '-Some text';
  ListBox1.Items.Add('String value : ' + lStrVal);

  lDateVal := EncodeDate(2000, 1, 1);
  lDateTimeVal := EncodeDate(2000, 1, 1) + EncodeTime(1, 0, 0, 0);

  lResult := TryStrToDate(lStrVal, lDateVal);
  if lResult then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - TryStrToDate : TRUE')
  else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - TryStrToDate : FALSE');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('DateTime value: ' + DateTimeToStr(lDateVal));

  lResult := TryStrToDateTime(lStrVal, lDateTimeVal);
  if lResult then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - TryStrToDateTime : TRUE')
  else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - TryStrToDateTime : FALSE');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('DateTime value: ' + DateTimeToStr(lDateTimeVal));

  // Reset
  lDateVal := EncodeDate(2000, 1, 1);
  lDateTimeVal := EncodeDate(2000, 1, 1) + EncodeTime(1, 0, 0, 0);

  lResult := TryStrToDateTime(lStrVal, lDateTimeVal) and TryStrToDate(lStrVal, lDateVal);
  if lResult then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Combined : TRUE')
  else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Combined : FALSE');
  ListBox1.Items.Add('DateTime value: ' + DateTimeToStr(lDateTimeVal));

  ListBox1.Items.Add('');
  lStrVal := '01/01/2019 10:00';
  ListBox1.Items.Add('String value : ' + lStrVal);

  lResult := TryStrToDateTime(lStrVal, lDateTimeVal) and TryStrToDate(lStrVal, lDateVal);
  if lResult then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Combined : TRUE')
  else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Combined : FALSE');

  try
    lDateTimeVal := VarToDateTime(lStrVal);
    lResult := true;
  except
    lResult := false;
  end;

  if lResult then
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Using Variant : TRUE')
  else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(' - Using Variant : FALSE');
```

This leaves me with the question if this means TryStrToDateTime is incorrectly implemented in comparison to TryStrToDate?  As a minimum there seems to be a contradiction on the "design" of the functions; "string value **is** a Date" versus "string value **begins with** a DateTime". Unless I am missing something...

Comment: FWIW; I have edited the code in my answer as the solution to combine TryStrToDateTime and TryStrToDate does not work. For example; TryStrToDate will fail on '01/01/2019 00:00' which is a valid DateTime!  After some trial and error I came up with VarToDateTime in a try-except.  For me this seems to work as required now....